# How to scan a database file for hex string in Java

Tags: java, hex

I have tried to find the answer to this but it's now 1am and I'm a little tired.

Could someone point me in the right direction please, what I want to do is scan a file using Java (.wmdb database file) for a pattern of hex values and then pull out the hex value after this pattern.

E.g
1. Scan for a hex value of "6B 4A 80 10 00 00 00 00 00" 
2. Pull out the hex values until the scanner reaches a value of "00 00 28"
3. Repeat

I'm sure there is an easy way I have missed by using the binary IO but I just can't seem to work it out. While I'm not after the answer an kick in the right direction or a simple example would help me a great deal.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, there is a easy way to do this. Just convert your begin match and end match representation into sequences of `byte`s. Then search for the beginning sequence in the `java.io.InputStream` and pull out the values until you match the end match. For matching you may use one of the [well-known algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm).

Here's example of naive implementation, that will gather all the byte sequences between beginMatch and endMatch:

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> pullOutBytes(InputStream stream, ArrayList<Integer> beginMatch, ArrayList<Integer> endMatch)
        throws IOException {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> pulledOut = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    int b;
    BeginSearch:
    while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
        int beginMatchIndex = 0;
        if (b != beginMatch.get(beginMatchIndex)) {
            continue BeginSearch;
        }
        beginMatchIndex++;
        while ((b = stream.read()) != -1 && beginMatchIndex < beginMatch.size()) {
            if (b != beginMatch.get(beginMatchIndex)) {
                continue BeginSearch;
            }
            beginMatchIndex++;
        }
        if (beginMatchIndex < beginMatch.size()) {
            break;
        }
        int endMatchIndex = 0;
        ArrayList<Integer> pull = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        pull.add(b);
        while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
            pull.add(b);
            if (b == endMatch.get(endMatchIndex)) {
                if (++endMatchIndex == (endMatch.size() - 1)) {
                    while (endMatchIndex > 0) {
                        pull.remove(pull.size() - 1);
                        endMatchIndex--;
                    }
                    pulledOut.add(pull);
                    continue BeginSearch;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return pulledOut;
}
```